# Qual a melhor forma de criar Posts Relacionados com PHP?

Tags: php, sql, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho um sistema que utilizo, mas queria ter um sistema para deixar mais filtrado a busca por posts relacionados, atualmente utilizo o `REGEXP` do `SQL` para fazer, já utilizei o `LIKE` e os resultados não me agradaram, alguém tem alguma ideia nova de como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na minha opinião, a melhor forma de criar um sistema de posts relacionados seria utilizando o conceito de tags. Assim como CMS's fazem, por exemplo, Wordpress.

Para cada post você relaciona ele com tags, palavras-chaves relacionadas a ele, se eu criar um post sobre um carro, por exemplo um Camaro, eu iria colocar tags como por exemplo: carro, chevrolet, automóvel, gasolina e assim por diante.

Para isso, você precisaria criar algumas tabelas no seu banco de dados para fazer o relacionamento.

Em uma [pesquisa rápida](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=tag+system+php&oq=tag+system+php&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2407j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8), você consegue encontrar publicações que podem te auxiliar.

Boa sorte e bons estudos ;)

Answer (score 1):

O mais provavel é que vc terá de fazer o sistema que vai lhe atender.

Existem CMS's (Drupal, Wordpress), mas vc teria de fazer uma migração do seu sistema o q

dependendo da situação pode ser bem mais complicado.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira é criar um campo do tipo lista, onde você pode especificar manualmente os posts relacionados, muitos plugins funcionam exatamente assim.

As vezes os posts relacionados pela busca automática, retornam posts com pouca coesão e/ou sentidos diferentes que fazem uso palavras chaves semelhantes. A não ser que você desenvolva um algorítimo a lá Google para relacionar posts.

Ninguém melhor do que o redator para saber o que é realmente relacionado o post em questão.

Você pode acabar tendo também a necessidade de relacionar um post em específico, e essa solução também irá lhe atender perfeitamente.

Você pode criar uma busca automática do tipo ajax para procurar posts que sejam semelhantes, e ajudar na pesquisa do post ideal, como acontece na hora que você cria uma pergunta aqui no StackOverflow mas deixe a decisão final sempre com o redator.

É uma solução rápida e fácil de implementar e claro bem funcional.

E sobre o `LIKE`, convido você a ver esse [vídeo](https://www.eventials.com/akitaonrails/como-nao-fazer-pesquisas-usando-like/) do grande Fábio Akita.

Comment: Haja paciência pra colocar manualmente cada post relacionado...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Sinceramente acredito que não seja nem um pouco trabalhoso. Para escrever um bom post, o redator terá que buscar informações e fontes, se aprofundar no assunto, redigir todo o texto, revisar e corrigi-lo até o ponto final e então publicar. Isso sim é trabalhoso :)